# Document Indexing Asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-search, indexing-service

I am tasked with indexing a large number of documents (allowing for full-text search) and then searching this index using ASP.net

I am using a Windows Server 2012 environment.

I have done some reading up but I'm still not sure what the indexing service to use.

I have read about 'Microsoft Indexing Services' (I have read this is obsolete) and 'Windows Search' service.

Can anyone make a recommend a suitable service to use and ideally some pointers as to how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Lucene .Net](http://lucenenet.apache.org/). It's a .Net port of the Lucene search index. It's an Apache project & might be just what you're looking for.